# find string in azure blob file

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell, azure-cli

Is there a way to find a string within a blob file with powershell/azure cli?

I have thousands of json files to move around and the only way to determine what file goes where is by a bit of text WITHIN the document itself. I was hoping to do a quick pattern match and for every blob with X in it move it to Y with az copy.

All I have determined so far that is that to do the "document cracking" bit I need Azure cognitive services (or azure search)  but even then i would need to create a c# app to interact with it the way I want to (would lie to avoid if possible)

The above suggests I can't - but I guess i'm hoping my Google-Fu was a bit off and that some out there has had such luck in the way i'd like to do it!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell to read the content of the blob using Get-AzureStorageBlobContent

```
$latestDeploymentBlob = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Blob app.version -Container $container -Context $blobContext 
$latestDeployment = $latestDeploymentBlob.ICloudBlob.DownloadText()
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/get-azurestorageblobcontent?view=azurermps-6.13.0

then you can combine it with Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy to move blobs between containers

```
$blobs | Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -Context $sourceContext -DestContext $destinationContext -DestContainer $DestinationContainerName -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have get the blob, can use `DownloadText()` to get the content, and use `Select-String` to do string matching

```
# Params
$azStorageAccountName = "str01" # Name of your storage account 
$azResourceGroupName = "rg01" # Resource group name where storage account lives
$azContainerName = "containerName"
$blobPrefix  = "some/prefix"
$searchString = "sometext"

# Get all blobs
$connectionContext = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $azResourceGroupName -AccountName $azStorageAccountName).Context
$blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $azContainerName -Prefix $blobPrefix -Context $connectionContext

$blobs | ForEach-Object {
    $blobText = $blob.ICloudBlob.DownloadText()              
    $matchResults = $blobText | Select-String -Pattern $searchString
    if ($matchResults.Matches.Length -gt 0) {
        # If match - do somehting
    }
    else {
        # Else - do something
    }
}
```